# Refresh table that connected to data source via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new in VBA so I don't know all the functionalities.
I have an Excel table that links to an external data source in ERP, when I click the 'Refresh' button the table gets updated properly from the data source. The problem is that I added a button that has to replace the refreshing functionality. I added a macro that gets triggered after the button click and tried to refresh the table via VBA code. Here is the macro:

```
Private lastRefreshDate As Date

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim con As WorkbookConnection
    'Dim db As Database
    ' Set the worksheet and table
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("kitaron")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table_ExternalData_1")
    
    
    If lastRefreshDate = 0 Then
        result = MsgBox("The Excel last modified date is XXX, do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
    Else
        result = MsgBox("The Excel last modified date is " & lastRefreshDate & ", do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
    End If
    
    If result = vbYes Then
        'tbl.Refresh
        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
'        For Each con In ThisWorkbook.Connections
'            con.Refresh
'        Next con
        'SendKeys "%{F5}"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The table gets updated partially, only when new rows are added, but not when rows get deleted or modified in the data source.

Thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: When refreshing queries using VBA you must turn OFF `Enable background refresh` in the Query properties - that way the VBA will wait until the query has completed

Comment: Another problem that I have now is that Worksheet Change event runs twice. First time because I triggered the event by pressing the button, second time happens because the table gets changed and it triggers this event automatically.

Comment: Try using `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start of your macro - remember to put it back on again afterwards with `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't work because it blocked the event from being triggered after calling 'refresh' function, but I added Application.EnableEvents = True in the beginning of the button event, Application.EnableEvents = False at the beginning of the Worksheet Change event, Application.EnableEvents = False at the end of the Worksheet Change event and Application.EnableEvents = False at the end of the button event. Maybe not all of them are necessary but it's working.

Comment: Remove the lines you added to the button event - you are leaving the application in a non-responsive state after the button push. By "macro" I should have made it clear that I meant your Worksheet_Change macro - apologies